# List of all table and column level privileges for a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

What is the easiest way to list all table-level and column-level privileges for a MySQL database?  I need to know what level of customized access has been granted for a specific database and which users have fine-tuned access to certain tables and/or columns.

Comment: probably more of a http://dba.stackexchange.com question next time.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list table level privileges, you can query [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-privileges-table.html).

> The `TABLE_PRIVILEGES` table has these columns:
>
> - `GRANTEE` : the name of the account to which the privilege is granted, in `'user_name'@'host_name'` format.
> - [...]
> - `TABLE_NAME` : the name of the table.
> - `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` : The privilege granted. The value can be any privilege that can be granted at the table level; [...] . Each row lists a single privilege, so there is one row per table privilege held by the grantee.

To list column level privileges, have a look at [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-privileges-table.html).

**All table/column level privileges for a specific database:**

```
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLE_PRIVILEGES` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database';
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMN_PRIVILEGES` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database';
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!  I added the actual queries to find all table and column-level privileges for a specific database.

Comment: Welcome @LStarky !

Answer (score 1):

Using [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-show-grants.html) from percona toolkit.